# WPF: Cannot bind bitmap source in animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a simple animation that alternate two frames changing the image. It works perfectly until I try to bind the bitmapimage urisource.

```
<Image Stretch="Fill">
<Image.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames  
                    BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=FrameDuration}" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.000000">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="Assets/frame1.png" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames  
                    BeginTime="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=FrameBeginTime}" Duration="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=FrameDuration}"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0000000">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="Assets/frame2.png" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Image.Triggers>
```

I tried these two bindings but none of them work:

XAML:

```
<BitmapImage Source="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=FrameUri1}"  />
```

Code:

```
public Uri FrameUri1 { get { return _frameUri1; } set { _frameUri1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("FrameUri1"); } }
```

and

XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ElementName=CosoControl, Path=BitmapSource}"  />
```

Code:

```
public ImageSource BitmapSource
    {
        get
        {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Myassembly;component/Assets/frame1.png");
            bitmap.EndInit();
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
```

I read other threads with similar issue, but I'm quite new to WPF/C# and I could not figure out how to solve it. I read about IValueConverter but no idea how to arrange that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to use diff. images with proper binding and hide them. Then animate opacity/visibility of the needed one.

```
<Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#FF341A1A" Height="200">            
        <Border.Background>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Grid>
                    <Image x:Name="Img1" Visibility="Collapsed" Source="{Binding Text, ElementName=MyControl1}"/>
                    <Image x:Name="Img2" Visibility="Collapsed" Source="{Binding Text, ElementName=MyControl2}"/>
                </Grid>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Border.Background>
    <Border.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                Duration="0:0:3"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Img1"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                >
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>                                
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>                            
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Border.Triggers>
</Border>
```

Comment: Do not answer specifically to the question, but this approach has more sense with XAML